# javascript (ReactJS), how to execute a reference of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a function that I want to use in a `onClick`, such as this

*using ReactJS and Semantic-UI

```
<Table.HeaderCell
  onClick={this.handleSort(items)}
>
```

where the function returns a reference of a function, such as this

```
handleSort = (items) => () => {
    console.log('now')
}
```

then, how can I execute this function outside of the onClick event? What doesn't work:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSort.call(items);
    this.handleSort(items);
}
```

Comment: You got your answer but as far as I know, this is not using the function by its reference. You are currying the function here. So, whenever `Table.HeaderCell` is rendered this function is recreated every time. If you do this to use the `items` as an argument, maybe there are better ways. For example, if the `items` is in your state or it is coming from a prop, you can use it directly instead of currying the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleSort` returns a function, you'll need to invoke it with `()`, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSort(items)();
}
```

Comment: Not at all, just a simple oversight :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to execute the inner function that logs 'now' to the console.

As a clarification: `this.handleSort(items)` returns a anonymous function:
`() => {
    console.log('now')
}`

In order to call it, you may do: `this.handleSort(items)()` to immediately invoke the inner function.

See:

```js
var handleSort = (items) => () => {
  console.log('now')
}

// holds the inner function part
var innerFunction = handleSort([]);
console.log(innerFunction.toString());

// Equivalent ways to call it directly
innerFunction();
handleSort([])();
```